# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger Pluginにて「ビルドしない」に流す方法

Tags: jenkins

JenkinsのGerrit Trigger Pluginには結果のコマンド送信の種類に
開始 / 成功 / 失敗 / 不安定 / ビルドしない
があります。

成功や失敗はジョブ側でexit 0/1等をすれば、それぞれ成功/失敗に設定したコマンドが実行出来るのですが、
「ビルドしない」や「不安定」はジョブ側でどのような結果を返せば実行されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マルチポスト先で回答を頂きました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267742/how-to-return-not-built-to-gerrit-trigger-plugin

Not Buildはビルドがタイムアウトした場合にセットされるものではないか、ということで明示的にセットできる種別ではなさそうです。

---

追記
力技ですがshellから以下を実行することで「ビルドしない」のシナリオに流すことが出来ました。
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/stop